# clojure macro: unable to resolve symbol

Tags: clojure

Clojure beginner, trying macros. I'm writing the following macro

```
(defmacro f [exp]
  (let [[a op b] exp]
    (list op a b)))

(f (1 + 2))
```

which works as intended.

However

I tried to replace the returned value from `(list op a b)` to `'(op a b)` and I get *unable to resolve symbol `op` in this context. I figured that the error is caused because `list` evaluates its arguments first, so I tried with `'(~op a b)`, but still get the same error. What am I understanding wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `op`, `a`, `b` can not be evaluated inside a quoted form. You need to use the backtick symbol instead of `'` (single quote) if you want to use `~` (unquote) [inside a macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/unquote).

```
(defmacro f [exp]
  (let [[a op b] exp]
    `(~op ~a ~b)))
```